# What is causing the Swift error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on an iOS app and I just got the error

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

at this section of code

```
            OnboardingSlide(title: "title 1", description: "description 1", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ex.png")),
            OnboardingSlide(title: "title 2", description: "description 2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ex.png")),
            OnboardingSlide(title: "title 3", description: "description 3", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ex.png"))
        ]
    }
```

I have not been able to find the source of the error even after reviewing common causes.

This is the rest of the file if it will help:

```
import UIKit

class OboardingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    @IBOutlet var nextBtn: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var slides: [OnboardingSlide] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slides = [
            OnboardingSlide(title: "title 1", description: "description 1", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ex.png")),
            OnboardingSlide(title: "title 2", description: "description 2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ex.png")),
            OnboardingSlide(title: "title 3", description: "description 3", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ex.png"))
        ]
    }
    
    @IBAction func nextBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
}

extension OboardingViewController:
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView( _ collectionView:
        UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return slides.count
    }
    func collectionView( _ collectionView:
        UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OnboardingCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! OnboardingCollectionViewCell
        cell.setup(slide: slides[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

The debug window shows this:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file ~/Onboarding/OboardingViewController.swift, line 25
2022-01-15 18:21:19.942566-0600 Spree[11798:759568] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file ~/Onboarding/OboardingViewController.swift, line 25
(lldb)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Usually when you encounter this it means it is a runtime error which means there is an instruction that is trying to execute that the compiler could not catch. My guess would be that the app cannot find "ex.png" from your bundle however, it is difficult to tell without more information. Can you debug in XCode and show *exactly* which line is the issue as well as the debug windows output? That tends to help pinpoint problems like these.

Comment: Most likely a forced or implicitly unwrapped optional is `nil`. Check your outlets are connected correctly. Set an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Also, image literal is deprecated. Use `UIImage(named:)`

Comment: Where does setup come from?